# Data Validation Dropdown With Filtered Data Range

Tags: validation, google-sheets, filter, dropdown, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to use data in column D
For a drop down in another sheet (data validation)
Only items where column A is less than 9

I tried List from a range
But it looks like you cannot put a formula in the range box
e.g.

```
=FILTER(GrpsTY!D2:D, GrpsTY!A2:A < 9)
```

Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I assume you were looking to avoid using a helper column?  Otherwise creating your filtered list of values, possibly placed on another sheet, and pointing to that list for your data validation, would achieve your objective, wouldn't it?

Comment: @kirkg13 Yes, I could do that. But I'm trying to avoid things like that if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formulas are not supported in data validation. the best course of action is to create a helper column with your filtered entries and then feed it to data validation.

Comment: Rats! I was hoping there was a way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe they have added the functionality since the most recent answer (last July, 2020)?

I'm trying to figure out a formula that will let me validate data using a filtered list, and stumbled onto this:

[This image shows that Google Sheets supports data validation using a custom formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHiri.png)

For Criteria, select "Custom formula is" instead of the default, "List from a range".
Hope this helps anyone who comes after me :)

Comment: Good to know, Thanks!